# Есть сервер с многими доменами как задать SSL certificate всем доменам?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, letsencrypt

Linux debian 8, аpache server.

Доменов 5, есть ли способ сразу всем доменам дать ssl certificate ?

Comment: Да, сертификат для пяти доменов делается точно так же, как и сертификат для одного домена и любого другого количества доменов (но не более 100 на один сертификат).

Answer (score 2):

С помощью certbot:
в апаче создаёшь алиас, чтобы на все твои домены certbot проверял в одном месте:

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/certbot.conf
Alias /.well-known/ /var/www/html/.well-known/
<Directory /var/www/html/.well-known/>
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

далее закачиваешь certbot и делаешь сертификаты:

```
certbot certonly --webroot --agree-tos --email admin@site.su -w /var/www/html -d site.su -d domen.su -d example.com -d ...
```

Если не нравятся бесплатные сертификаты, то можешь купить, но выбирай тогда с поддержкой SAN

Если нужно само-подписные, то нужно сгенерить csr с поддержкой  SAN и когда подписываешь серт, то её тоже нужно добавить -extensions к openssl ca.
Но об этом можно отдельную статью написать.